# If we put "of" instead of "to" in the example sentences

Tags: prepositions

In the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, 10th meaning of the preposition "to" is explained as such:

> *used to show a relationship between one person or thing and another*
>
> the Japanese ambassador to France
>
> the key to the door

My question is that if we put "of" instead of "to" in the example sentences given, will the meaning change?

Comment: Yes, it will, at least for the first one. Why do you think they are the same?

Comment: The meaning of the first one changes to mean, "*The ambassador **from** France, who happens to be Japanese*". The second one is just bad grammar. We don't say "of" there.